# pyautogui in the same window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I use the command `pyautogui.press('enter')` in a for loop that runs for many times and for a long time.

The problem is that if I run the code and I want to do something else, happens that enter is pressed in the window I'm working on and not only on the terminal as I would like.

Is there a way to run `pyautogui.press('enter')` only on the terminal and, in the meantime, work on other windows?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, pyautogui manually moves the mouse so you can't be doing something else...